# SMTP on Magento 1.4.0.1

Tags: smtp, magento-1.4

I want to configuration SMTP on Magento 1.4.0.1. Does someone know extension for SMTP mail for Magento 1.4.0.1 similar with SMTP Pro ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html ). Also I find one code on internet ( http://pravams.com/2011/07/30/magento-send-email-using-smtp/ ) who is also don't work on Magento 1.4.0.1.

My question is: **Does some know how to enable SMTP on Magento 1.4.0.1?**

Answer (score 0):

I have used with success this extension in Magento 1.4 and 1.7:

[www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html)

It's very useful and easy to configure.
I think is better to use the extension instead of create a code

Another extension is:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-smtp-artson-it.html

But believe me is better aschroder extension because is more configurable and has less bug than advanced-smtp-artson.

Comment: Which version on Magento 1.4.x.x. Because I tested in magento 1.4.1.1 and is work perfect, but is not work on Magento 1.4.0.1. Also on the extension page is write that support Magento 1.4 and Magento 1.4.1.1 but not Magento 1.4.0.1. did you tested on Magento 1.4.0.1?

Comment: My version of magento it was 1.4.1 I think. You can try it yourself if doesn't work unistall it or try the second link @JovanovJordan